# How to use Hcodecs to write wav files

Tags: haskell, audio

I am trying to get started playing a bit around with sound in haskell.

I imagine that i will ind up with a list representing the soundwave. My problem is taking this list, and turning it into the `Audio` type from the Hcodecs library, so that I can use the library to create a wave file.

So the question is: How to I go from a list to an `Audio`?

Comment: List of what? There are several ways of representing sound or music.

Comment: Lists of `Word8`, `Int16`, `Int32` or `Int64`. `Audio`, like list, is also a container type, so I guessed that the function turning a list into an `Audio` would not have to take into account the type of the elements, since they can be anything. But if i want to write the `Audio` as a wav file, the type of the contents has satisfy type constraints meaning that it must be one of the above mentioned types.

Comment: So do I understand correctly that Haskell can create 64-bit WAV files?

Comment: Haskell can write arbitrary data to files, but I guess you are asking about the Hcodecs library in particular? From a cursory look at the source, it seems like it does indeed write 64 bit samples to the WAV file when given `Int64` audio samples. But it is still a normal WAV file with a 32 bit length field (which means it is limited to 4GB of data). Sometimes 64 bit WAV refers to an extension which uses a 64 bit length field. Hcodecs does not seem to support this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crucial bit is `type SampleData a = UArray Int a`. So you can just use the `IArray` instance of `Data.Array.Unboxed.UArray` to [construct this container](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/array/0.3.0.3/doc/html/Data-Array-IArray.html#g:3). Then all that's left to do is use `Audio sampleRate channelNumber sampleData`, and you're all set.

Comment: Thank you! I have now managed to create a 5 second long A tone :)